# Azure App Service - Give file as input to application published app service azure

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have published a web application on App service. Web Application is working correctly on Local run. In a web application, I am taking thumbprint, Certificate file path, and certificate password as input from the user. Certificate details are input correctly into Azure App service published Web application but getting the error " The system can't found the specified path".

Here I am passing local machine contained certificate path from C Drive or D drive.

Please guide how to resolve error.
[Please check below image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4SOdZ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your path or file `OAuth2.0_AzureAD_A` in the `scm` site, under the path `D:\home\site`. Like below.

**We can operate on the path at this level and below. The others should be unchangeable. .**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer..! Your explanation was really helped me.